# How to use a single buffer object as both VBO and UBO (possibly any other kind of buffers also) in opengl

Tags: opengl

My question relates to how allocations are handled in opengl.
If you create a buffer object using `glGenBuffers(1, &id)` then let's say populate it with a mesh's vertex data using `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id)` and `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)`. The question I have now is : will the data I uploaded be bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER tag specifically? So could I for example later use `glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, id)` and use that data as a uniform buffer or does changing the associated target cause memory to be freed forcing me to use `glGetBufferSubData` to retrieve and re-upload the data now bound to the GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER tag? It seems intuitive that a buffer object keeps it's data as long as it is not deleted and that the target parameter is more to hint to the gpu where the data might be more optimally stored and what operations might be done with the buffer. What effects does doing something like this have on the state of opengl and is there a recommended alternative other than duel-uploading or re-uploading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer target does not have any effect on the content of a buffer. A buffer itself doesn't even know to which target it is bound. You can at any time bind the buffer to any other target and it can even be bound to multiple targets at the same time.

Buffer targets are only used by the API to determine which buffer a command should operate on. For example, `glBufferData` requires you to bind the buffer to the same target that you pass to it. But it doesn't really matter which target you are using. Some other commands, like `glVertexAttribPointer` expect a buffer to be bound to a certain target, but also here the binding doesn't alter/modify the buffer itself.

Note, that [Direct State Access (DSA)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) methods which are core since OpenGL 4.5 do not use binding targets at all while providing the same functionality as the stateful methods.